# Closed form solution to recurrence: $g(n)=(k-2)g(n-1)+(k-1)g(n-2)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

For the number of paths with exactly $n$ hops from one node to another in a $k$ node fully connected graph, we get the following recurrence:

$$g_n=(k-2)g_{n-1}+(k-1)g_{n-2}$$

With $g_1=1$, $g_0=0$ and $g_m=0 \;\; \forall \;\; m<0$.

Is there a way to get a closed form for this recurrence? For $k=3$, this yields the [Jacobsthal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobsthal_number#cite_note-2).

---

For future reference, this recurrence represents the number of paths from one node to another in a $k$ node fully connected undirected graph and has the solution:

$$g(n) = \frac{(k-1)^n-(-1)^n}{(k)}$$

---

My attempt:

Let's try to construct the generating function.

$$B(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty g_n x^n$$

We get:

$$B(x) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty ((k-2)g_{n-1}+(k-1)g_{n-2})x^n$$

$$=>B(x) = (k-2)x\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty g_{n-1}x^{n-1}+(k-1)x^2\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty g_{n-2}x^{n-2}$$
$$=(k-2)x B(x)+(k-1)x^2 B(x)$$

But this just makes $B(x)$ cancel out and we don't get an expression for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your attempt to find the generating function doesn't actually make use of the initial conditions $g_0 = 0$, $g_1 = 1$ at all; you need to encode these somehow into the expression to actually get a useful result. (Also, the recurrence doesn't even hold for $g_1$, so we need to distinguish that case at the very least.) In particular, we can write
$$
B(x) = 0 \cdot x^0 + 1 \cdot x^1 + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} ((k-2)g_{n-1} + (k-1)g_{n-2}) x^n.
$$
Can you take it from here?

Alternatively, instead of using generating functions, just construct the characteristic polynomial $\lambda^2 - (k-2) \lambda - (k-1) = 0$, which factorises as $(\lambda - (k-1))(\lambda + 1)=0$. So we can write the general form as
$$g_n = A\cdot (k-1)^n + B \cdot (-1)^n,$$
from which you can use your initial conditions to finish.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot. I think there is a typo. Should be $g_n=A (k-1)^n+B (-1)^n$

Comment: @RohitPandey The recurrence in the title is different to the one in the post; which one is it meant to be?

Comment: My bad. There was a typo in the one in the title.

Comment: You're sure the title was the one which had a typo? If you want it to coincide with Jacobsthal numbers for $k = 3$ then it should be the other way around, i.e. $g_n = (k-2) g_{n-1} + (k-1) g_{n-2}$, unless I'm mistaken. (I've also edited the answer as if this is the case, and it gives me the solution you suggested, so I assume this is what you want?)

Comment: You're right. Fixed it. Title was correct.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(n)=t^n$, then
$$t^2-(k-2)t-(k-1) \implies t=k-1,-1$$
Hence
$$g(n)=A (k-1)^n + B (-1)^n$$

**The Proof**

Let $ax^2+bx+c=0$ has two roots $p,q$. then
$$ap^2+bp+c=0~~~(1), ~~aq^2+bq+c=0~~~(2)$$
Multiply (1) and (2) by $C_1 p^n$ and $C_2 q^n$ and add them
we get $$(a C_1 p^{n+2}+ C_2 q^{n+2}))+b (C_1 p^{n+1}+ C_2 q^{n+1})+ c(C_1 p^n + C_2 q^n)=0~~~~(3)$$
Define $$U_n=C_1 p^n+ C_2 q^n~~~~(4)$$
So (3) becomes
$$aU_{n+2}+bU_{n+1}+cU_n=0~~~~~~(5)$$
Hence the solution of (5) is given by (4).

Comment: Is there a proof for why this characteristic polynomial based approach works for recurrences?

Comment: @Rohit Pandey Yes, please see my edit.